# What is the difference between summary and description in GitHub Desktop?

Tags: github, git-commit, github-for-mac

Though I don't find it annoying or anything like that but I just wanted to know how is specifying either of the `summary` or `description` different while making a `commit` using the desktop version on GitHub? How do I provide these two together on terminal using `git commit` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The summary is the first line of a commit message: it summarizes the *reason* for the commit (why, not what)
See "[The Art of the Commit](http://alistapart.com/article/the-art-of-the-commit)"

The rest goes into the description.

[image]

---

By convention, that first line is not supposed to be more than 50 characters:
See [this template](https://gist.github.com/adeekshith/cd4c95a064977cdc6c50)

```
# <type>: (If applied, this commit will...) <subject> (Max 50 char)
# |<----  Using a Maximum Of 50 Characters  ---->|


# Explain why this change is being made
# |<----   Try To Limit Each Line to a Maximum Of 72 Characters   ---->|

# Provide links or keys to any relevant tickets, articles or other resources
# Example: Github issue #23
```

Other Git GUIs do enfornce the same summary/description convention, [like Atomio](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/towards-better-git-commit-messages-using-atom-6dbda5e14984#.ac9rhogn5):

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*dSJ0TgQUPX2ukRwgZi9RBQ.gif]