# Does Visual Studio 2022 have a textarea for git commit description?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Similar to GitHub Desktop which offers different sections designated for commit **summary** and commit **description**, I expected Visual Studio (2022) to offer the same. However, contrary to my expectations, I was unable to find the input field for commit description.

I CAN use Git command “git commit -m "Summary" -m "Description"” to achieve the same result, but the point is this feature is so rudimentary that I think *I* might not have been able to find it.

Comment: Press Enter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369602/what-is-the-difference-between-summary-and-description-in-github-desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** It's not necessary because you simply use a blank line.

**Details:**
No, Visual Studio doesn't have separate textboxes for commit title/summary and the description/body. The reason is that by convention a commit message simply separates the two by a blank line:

```
This is the title; ideally less than 50 chars

This is the body. Ideally each line in the body is less than 72 chars.
Notice the body is separated from the title by a blank line. Most UIs
only have a single textbox for the commit message and this is how you
separate them. Some commit messages might even have a "trailer" at the
bottom as well, like this:

Co-authored-by: TTT <ttt@ttt.com>
```

Side Note, when you write a commit message from the command line, some consoles (e.g. Bash) will let you press `<Enter>` while writing the commit message without needing to use multiple `-m` options. For example:

```
git commit -m "This is the commit title

And this is the body of the commit message."
```